# BitString - Can't load my value in BitStream

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitstring

A simple question.

I have a <\class 'str'> (checked) with a 124 length hexa content named hexapacket.

I'm doing like this:

```
import bitstring

data = BitStream(hexa=hexapacket)
# My processing on bits
```

But it raises errors like it can't find the length etc ..

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0edd0e000201a9017dc0c3898000000000'
```

and

```
ValueError: Don't understand length '0edd0e000201a9017dc0c3898000000000' of token.
```

and

```
KeyError: ('0edd0e000201a9017dc0c3898000000000', 0)
```

Could you help to make it working ? It's the solution i wanted to parse datas.

EDIT :
I tried some debug and the output is strange, the hex() cast and the bin() cast add 0b and 0x at the start of the string and i have handle it by string = string[2:]
But it still doesn't work with BitStream from bitstring.
I precise that the original packet comes from pyshark and i casted the packet.data.data into string.

CODE :

```
if hexapacket.find(':') != -1:
    hexapacket = ''.join(packet.split(":"))
if hexapacket.find('0x') != -1:
    hexapacket = hexapacket[2:]
msgid = int(bin(int(hexapacket[:4],16))[2:-2],2)
messagetype = dict_ids[msgid]
lenoflen = int(bin(int(hexapacket[:4],16))[-2:],2)
print("ID: %d\nMSG: %s\nLoL: %d\n" % (msgid,messagetype,lenoflen))
print("My hexapacket\n%s" % hexapacket)
raw = BitStream(hex=hexapacket)
```

OUTPUT :

```
ID: 950
MSG: GameMapMovementRequestMessage
LoL: 1

My hexapacket
0ed93c0003519a418c418b050c0405fafb5a21348190b66ecc166c09f832a7324069fcd9e19ea6be654b26b42563908947857a2b3cb25ce920837262a5fb69
```

ERRORS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bitstring.py", line 612, in tokenparser
    length = int(length)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 232, in <module>
    messages = PacketProcessing().splitProcess(packet)
  File "main.py", line 182, in splitProcess
    data1 = raw.read('pad:%d'%datalen*8)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bitstring.py", line 3880, in read
    _, token = tokenparser(fmt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bitstring.py", line 622, in tokenparser
    raise ValueError("Don't understand length '{0}' of token.".format(length))
ValueError: Don't understand length '0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0pad:0' of token.
```

OUTPUT of repr(hexapacket) and type(hexapacket):

```
'0ed93a0002118b11a8050c04053e03bcd154bb84543c9b2a7992280bddf099b126acd1e75bf274842565e499d9e0221f86c02fa26d0a859ce426e63a74'
```

and

```
<class 'str'>
```

ANSWER : Use BitString module for Python3.x, it's easier to cast and read data.

Comment: Did you mean `hex` instead of `hexa`?

Comment: Yeah a mistake writing it on SO. I add in 2 mins the code and the output if it may help you to help me :D

Comment: Could you update the question to include the output of `repr(hexapacket)`?

Comment: Added. Thank you :). I'll add a type(hexapacket) to be sure.

Comment: I don't know how but between the time i post the question and added your requests, the bug wasn't the same but now, i can't read from buffer --'. I'll give it a try now. Thank's for helping :)

Comment: `data1 = raw.read('pad:%d'%datalen*8)` -> `data1 = raw.read('pad:%d' % (datalen*8))`

Answer (score 2):

It should work, if you specify `hex=` keyword argument:

```
>>> import bitstring
>>> bitstring.BitStream(hex='0edd0e000201a9017dc0c3898000000000')
BitStream('0x0edd0e000201a9017dc0c3898000000000')
```

Comment: Thx for answering but it still doesn't work. I've some problem with python cast int(x,16) int(x,2) add 0x and 0b before the string and i tried with and without. like BitStream(hex = packet[2:]) but it still doesn't work.